# perl regex multiple words in a line

Tags: perl

I am trying to split these values , I am not getting as expected

```
$line = "sep 11 14:06:18 github-01-com sshd[4609]: Received disconnect from 192.168.1.1: disconnected by user";

if($line =~ /^(.*)\s+(\w+)/){
print "$1\n$2\n";
```

I am trying to get output like these

```
$val1 = "sep 11 14:06:18";
$val2 = "github-01-com";
$val3 = "sshd[4609]:"
$val4 = "Received disconnect from 192.168.1.1: disconnected by user"
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this specific line, you can decode it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $line = "sep 11 14:06:18 github-01-com sshd[4609]: Received disconnect from 192.168.1.1: disconnected by user";

if ($line =~ m/^(\w+\s+\d+\s+(?:\d|:)+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)\s+(.*)$/) {
    print "\$1 = $1\n\$2 = $2\n\$3 = $3\n\$4 = $4\n";
}
```

Here is the output:

```
$1 = sep 11 14:06:18
$2 = github-01-com
$3 = sshd[4609]:
$4 = Received disconnect from 192.168.1.1: disconnected by user
```

By the way, depends on which kind of log file you are trying to parse, there may be exist some modules to do it, try to search them in [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/).

Comment: @scm You also could search modules to parse your log files in [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/).